Limit the number of CPUs used by QuestDB
I'm currently running an instance of QuestDB 7.4.2 and ingesting via http. I have 18 CPUs on the VM, but I am also running there Jenkins and Grafana.
I am noticing during periods of relatively higher load on Jenkins, that my QuestDB pool seems to cycle down using htop.
If I want to continue running these services on the same host, is there a recommended way to isolate the cpus so that say 2 are used to run Jenkins and Grafana, and the other 16 are dedicated to QuestDB?

From QuestDB point of view, you can set the shared.worker.count config variable to 16, or whichever value you prefer. This can be done directly at the conf/server.conf file or using the env variable QDB_SHARED_WORKER_COUNT.
As per the rest of the tools, I am not sure if they have similar controls, but you could always start via Docker and set limits for how many CPUs they can use.
